# How can I turn off logging in HSQL DB with URL parameter?

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, hsqldb, hypersql

I am using java-ee application running on wicket.

The problem is, that the connection to the HyperSQL database with JDBC creates a huge log file *.log. Example of my URL:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\database\text;hsqldb.sqllog=0;hsqldb.applog=0
```

I need to turn off the logging with some jdbc url parameter. I have tried these:

```
hsqldb.sqllog=0;hsqldb.applog=0;
```

That is not working, so I have tried this combination:

```
hsqldb.log_data=false;hsqldb.reconfig_logging=false
```

But with these parameters, when I stop the app, the data disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text.log` file is the record of transactions performed on your database. If you disable it with `hsqldb.log_data=false` the transactions are not persisted to disk. The name is derived from the file name on your database URL.

The `hsqldb.sqllog` and `hsqldb.applog` settings are for diagnostics and default to 0.

The `hsqldb.reconfig_logging=false` is also for diagnostics and works together with `hsqldb.applog` setting. These settings are discussed in the Guide: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_monitoring_operation

So if you want your data to survive when your app shuts down, you should not disable the default log. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/management-chapt.html#mtc_cache_persistence on how to reduce the size of the `text.log` file.

Comment: And what about the log_size parameter? When it will be e.g. hsqldb.log_size=1, will the data be persisted to disk? Thank you.

Comment: I have found this: When the size of the file reaches this value, a CHECKPOINT is performed and the the *.log file is cleared to size 0.
So the data will be persisted on disk. :)